# Programatically manipulating UITextField in cell that was created in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

[image: Here is the View]

I'm trying to change the UITextField in a TableView delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure cell here
    if ( indexPath.section == [self nameSectionNumber]) {
        if ( indexPath.row == [self firstNameRowNumber] ){
            UITextField *textFieldFromCell = [self retrieveUITextFieldFromCell:cell];
            textFieldFromCell.text = [self.person firstName];
        } else if ( indexPath.row == [self lastNameRowNumber] ) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.person lastName];
        }
    } else if ( indexPath.section == [self emailSectionNumber] ) {
        if ( indexPath.row == [self emailSectionHomeRowNumber] ) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.person homeEmail];
        } else if ( indexPath.row == [self emailSectionWorkRowNumber] ) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.person workEmail];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}


- (UITextField *)retrieveUITextFieldFromCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    // Need to grab UITextField from cell
    for (UIView *view in  cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            UITextField* txtField = (UITextField *)view;
            return txtField;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

If I don't try to modify the cell and just do

```
// Configure cell here
    if ( indexPath.section == [self nameSectionNumber]) {
        if ( indexPath.row == [self firstNameRowNumber] ){
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.person firstName];
        } else if ( indexPath.row == [self lastNameRowNumber] ) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.person lastName];
        }
    }
```

The UILabel ("First Name") is gone and the UITextField is gone, which is what I expect since I think its because of this code

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if ( cell == nil ) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
```

[image: Second view]

Note: Ignore the last name and email fields. I'm only focusing on first name at the moment to get that to look right.

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text.text`?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, or what your question is.

Comment: @rdelmar I've defined a UITextField in the storyboard on the UITableViewCell. I want to add text to it in code, but I'm having issues with doing so when I pull the cell out. I want to be able to add first name to the UITextField while keeping the "First Name" label that I specified.

Comment: I think the easiest and best way to do this, is to make a custom cell subclass, and make outlets to any controls that you need to access. You only need to set up outlets in the .h file, you don't need to add anything to the .m. It's very easy to do, and gives you cleaner code.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot get the cell out of the tableview. I've tried tags and unique cell identifiers. I did create a custom cell subclass though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you're defining a tableview with static cells. In this case you don't need to implement the data source delegate methods for the tableview and if you do you're basically overwriting the static cells you defined in the storyboard. If you need to set the content for these cells I suggest you define an IBOutlet for the cell and simply reference that outlet and modify the text property directly.

```
@interface ProfileViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameTextField;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastNameTextField;
@end

@implementation ProfileViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
        _firstNameTextField.text = @"John";
        _lastNameTextField.text = @"Smith";
    }

    ...
@end
```